# Lookup and extract db value based on input (Java & SQL Server)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, variables, recordset

New to java.
I am attempting to write a class that will input a username, run a query on the username to find the ID, and subsequently use that ID in "where clauses" on all my other classes.

This is the statement that I execute (which will only ever return a recordset of a single row):

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT AccountHolderId, Passcode from CIS4720.DBO.AccountHolder " +
"where Username = '" + logonName + "'";
```

Here is my attempt at extracting the ID via the username...

```
while (rset.next())
    {
        if(rset.getInt("Username")==logonName){
            int whosOnFirst = rset.getInt("AccountHolderId");
        }
```

I saw another answer on the forum that says you can't assign database values to variables.  If that is the case, what is a better strategy?

(Also, I realize I'm not parameterizing, but I'd like to get this working before fixing that issue.  This is for a course assignment so I am not worried about hack attacks).

P. S. Thanks I fixed the double equals sign (and the extra parenthesis) in the code above.

Comment: `rset.getInt("Username")` will get the column Username from the result but it also looks for an Integer column because of `getInt`. You are not selecting that column in the sql statement so will error out. Also, if you select it and get a string, use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare string. Also, one `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.

Comment: You can use `getString` to read Strings from the result set. You don't need to check the username and match it since your query should return exactly that user's data so I would remove the if condition entirely and just have the `getInt` line there.

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis after `Username` in the query.

Comment: Still have any issues? Seems like it should work with the changes mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @clinomaniac.  It is working now however when I put my whosOnFirst integer variable in another class, it does not recognize it.  I had thought that by declaring it in a class labeled "public class void" it would let me use this variable anywhere in my program.

Comment: That's a separate question. I'll post my comments as an answer and please accept it if it helped your issue. A `Class` cannot be void. That's for methods. You need to either make the variable public at the class level or have a getter. I can answer more in detail but that would need to be a separate question and would need additional information to answer accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some comments about the code:

- `rset.getInt("Username")` will get the column Username from the result but it also looks for an Integer column because of getInt. You are not selecting that column in the sql statement so will error out.
- If you select it and get a string, use `.equals()` instead of `==` to compare string. Also, one `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.
- You can use `getString` to read Strings from the result set.
- You don't need to check the username and match it since your query should return exactly that user's data so I would remove the if condition entirely and just have the getInt line there.